# Chef notifications within libraries

Tags: chef-infra, chef-recipe

I am trying to notify a ruby block within a library method from another method within the same library.

example

This is my first method (method A) which has a ruby block called FIRST and it notifies another ruby block called SECOND which is in method B.

```
module MyModule
def methodA
  ruby_block 'FIRST' do
    block do
      ## DO SOMETHING 
    end
  notifies :create, 'ruby_block[SECOND]', :delayed
  end
end

def methodB
  ruby_block 'SECOND' do
    block do
      ## DO SOMETHING 
    end
  action :nothing
  end
end
end
```

Somehow , the notification does not seem to work may be because the resource to be notified is present in a different method?

Comment: Right... Because you need to call `methodB` before `ruby_block 'SECOND'` exists in the run_context.

Comment: Hi Seth, So within methodA ( before the notifies)  , I need to call MethodB?

Comment: Yes. You need to get that resource into the collection

Comment: Can you please provide a simple example? or point me to one that exists alreadY?

Comment: If you call `methodB` before calling `ruby_block 'FIRST'` inside of `methodA` it should work.

Comment: Literally call the method... The example is "`methodB`".